# Facebook Like Box only working in iFrame

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I'm trying to utilize Facebook's "Like Box" with javascript. Here is the code snippet I put into my page.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/PageName" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Everything loads correctly besides the Newsfeed. Am I missing something? It's strange because when I use their iFrame method, it works perfect. But given the application I am unable to use iFrame.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPageName&amp;width&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Please keep in mind I am replacing "PageName" with the actual page name.

Comment: Is the `<div id="fb-root"></div><script type="text/javascript">....</script>` right after the `<body>` opens? The `div class="fb-like-box">` should be after that.

Comment: actually, that does not matter. in general, it´s even better to use the javascript AFTER fb-like-box - that is, if it would be synchronous, which is not the case anyway.

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Weird resolution, after implementing the iFrame and testing it... I reverted back to the javascript way and now it loads successfully... sometimes I love coding. Must have been a browser caching issue.*

Edit (Resolution)-

Turns out this is a bug on Facebook's end! If you are not logged in, you will see posts, if you are logged in, you will see nothing!